# How to create a page for a particular topic on Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion, site-proposal

I'm preparing for UPSC Civil Services exam in India, which attracts more than a million applications each year.
I'm taking management subject as optional Paper for this exam. I truly like Stack Overflow platform and its features for a Q&A platform much better than Quora. Hence I would like to start a page here.

Is there a way I can create a page here?

Comment: No, that is not possible on the sites in the SE network

Comment: The SE network does not consist of forums.

Comment: Any suggestions for a website that has similar functionality as SE and provides an option for forum??

Comment: @user2083097 the answer below covers the only possibility you have. You should accept that answer.

Answer (score 4):

Stack Exchange is a network of sites and not of forums or spaces. So you can't *create a page here similar to Quora Space, Facebook page etc.*

However, you can suggest proposals for new sites for the Stack Exchange network on [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/). But an essential condition for doing so is that you should have a **pre-existing community** before submitting a proposal.